# Multiline string not captured by regex

Tags: python, regex, multiline

When applying regex to a multiline string, I realize the regex may be correct according to rubular.com. The problem is that somehow it is not working against multiline text.  Question is, I attempted to do "item.strip()" and no change in behavior.

```
s = """ #if route rate 230.207.200.1', '', '   
(50.50.50.11,230.207.200.1)', """
for item in s: 
    match = re.findall(r'([0-9].[0-9].[0-9].[0-9],.........)', s) 
if match:
    print('match')
```

Comment: probably most tools for regex need some option to works with multiline.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any line ending matching or dot character in there?
Try setting the flags to either `re.DOTALL` or `re.MULTILINE`, for example:

`re.findall(r'...', s, flags=re.DOTALL)`